# Remove event listener added by click event, not in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, react-hooks, mouseevent

I have an table rendered by an component.

On each td, i have function onClick

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td onClick={handleClick}>a</td>
      <td onClick={handleClick}>a</td>
      <td onClick={handleClick}>a</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

On handleClick function, i add 3 more event listener: movedown, mousemove, mouseup to track the mouse for selecting

```
handleClick = (event) => {
  const mousedown = (e) => {...}
  event.target.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown)
  const mousemove = (e) => {...}
  const mouseup = (e) => {
    document.getElementById("tbl").removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
  }
  document.getElementById("tbl").addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
  document.getElementById("tbl").addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
}
```

The problem is: i can not remove mouseup event after each click, so there are many duplicates of mouseup event like this:

[image: duplicate]

I try to use the similar as useEffect at the end of handleClick:

`return () => document.getElementById("tbl").removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);`

but it seems not working

Can you help me to solve this? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use onmouseout to remove your event. useEffect return func only run when your tbl unmount :D

Comment: it seems not working, because in my case, the mouse up event need to be fired and removed while the mouse is still pointing in the table, not outside the table

Comment: how about remove old event before add a new event ?
el.removeEventListener('click', listenerFn)  el.addEventListener('click', listenerFn)

Comment: the problem is: i click an td, the table add 1 new mouseup event. i click other td, table add 1 more other event. So i think best solution for this case is: remove the event listener right after it occurs, like this: mouseup = (e) => {..., el.removeEventListener("mouseup")}. I've tested this and it works :D